# meteor accounts-github pkg does not display username after logging in

Tags: meteor, github, accounts

I have the following packages installed in my meteor app:

```
accounts-github 1.3.0
accounts-password 1.4.0
accounts-ui 1.1.9
github-config-ui 1.0.0
```

I display the login menu using {{> loginButtons}}

If I log in using a standard username and password it correctly displays the username after logging in. If I log in using github, it successfully logs me in but it doesn't display any username. The only thing that appears is the drop down arrow. Clicking that shows the sign out button.

This is my accounts config code.

```
Accounts.ui.config({
passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_AND_EMAIL"
});
```

Comment: Can you try running `Meteor.user()` in the browser console to see how the server return the username for two cases: 1. login using username & password and 2. login using github ?

Comment: standard log in = Meteor.user().username and github log in = Meteor.user().services.github.username.

Comment: I take a look at the source code of `accounts-ui` and I see this line: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js#L21. Apparently `accounts-ui` doesn't get the username from anything like `Meteor.user().services.github.username`, so `displayName` returns an empty string. I think to resolve this you should handle the username display yourself and don't use `accounts-ui`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the **user.username** field to be the Github username from the field **user.services.github.username**. You can do it inside the onCreateUser function.

```
 Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
    user.profile = options.profile;

    // If signed in with github
    if (user.services.github) {
        user.username = user.services.github.username
    }

    return user;
 });
```

This code should be server side and not inside Meteor.startup().